# Guava EventBus: How to return result from event handler

Tags: java, events, event-handling, guava

I have a web service which receives xml events from another system, process them using specific workflow and sends a list of potentials errors back as HTTP response.

Event processing workflow consists of several handlers (let's say: *Preprocessor*, *Persister* and *Validator*) implemented using [Guava's EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained). Handlers send events to each other. Something like this:

```
public class RequestHandler {

    @RequestMapping
    public Errors handleRequest(String xmlData) {
        eventBus.post(new XmlReceivedEvent(xmlData));
        ...
        return errors; // how to get errors object from the last handler in chain ? 
    }
}

public class Preprocessor {

    @Subscribe
    public void onXmlReceived(XmlReceivedEvent event) {
       // do some pre-processing
       ...  
       eventBus.post(new PreprocessingCompleteEvent(preprocessingResult)); 
    }
}

public class Persister {

    @Subscribe
    public void onPreprocessingComplete(PreprocessingCompleteEvent event) {
       // do some persistence stuff
       ...    
       eventBus.post(new PersistenceCompleteEvent(persistenceResult)); 
    }
}

public class Validator {

    @Subscribe
    public void onPersistenceComplete(PersistenceCompleteEvent event) {
       // do validation
       ...    
       eventBus.post(new ValidationCompleteEvent(errors)); // errors object created, should be returned back to the RequestHandler 
    }
}
```

The problem is: **how to return the processing result** deeply from *Validator* handler back to the starting point (*RequestHandler*), so user can receive HTTP response ?

I consider two options:

1. Set errors object to the initial XmlReceivedEvent and retrieve it after processing complete:

   ```
   public class RequestHandler {

       @RequestMapping
       public Errors handleRequest(String xmlData) {
           XmlReceivedEvent event = new XmlReceivedEvent(xmlData);
           eventBus.post(event);
           ...
           return event.getErrors(); 
       }
   }
   ```

However, in that case I will have to pass errors object to each event in the chain to make it available for *Validator* to fill it with real data.

1. Subscribe *RequestHandler* to *ValidationCompleteEvent* from *Validator* with populated errors object inside.

   ```
   public class RequestHandler {

       private Errors errors;

       @RequestMapping
       public Errors handleRequest(String xmlData) {
           XmlReceivedEvent event = new XmlReceivedEvent(xmlData);
           eventBus.post(event);
           ...
           return this.errors; // ??? 
       }

       @Subscribe
       public void onValidationComplete(ValidationCompleteEvent event) {
           this.errors = event.getErrors();
       }
   }
   ```

But, unfortunately, *RequestHandler* is a Spring stateless service (singleton), so I would like to avoid saving any data in class fields.

Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a workflow like that, you shouldn't be using a Guava `EventBus` for it. `EventBus` is specifically intended to allow events to be posted to subscribers without the event poster knowing or caring about what those subscribers are... as such, you can't return results to the poster of an event from subscribers.

It sounds to me like you should be doing something much more straightforward here, like injecting your preprocessor, persister and validator and calling their methods directly.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds reasonable. However, I'm afraid of creating such a God-Object, which holds references to all other application components. It could be really hard to test, how do you think?

Comment: @stoweesh: I don't know, from what you've described it doesn't sound like it would be a god object to me. The general approach if it _would_ become a god object would be to find things it does that logically go together and extract them in to another class. And use interfaces and inject services so that you can use fake implementations for easy testing of course.